# Pattern for delegating async behavior in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to design a class that exposes the ability to add asynchronous processing concerns. In synchronous programming, this might look like

```
   public class ProcessingArgs : EventArgs
   {
      public int Result { get; set; }
   } 

   public class Processor 
   {
        public event EventHandler<ProcessingArgs> Processing { get; }

        public int Process()
        {
            var args = new ProcessingArgs();
            Processing?.Invoke(args);
            return args.Result;
        }
   }


   var processor = new Processor();
   processor.Processing += args => args.Result = 10;
   processor.Processing += args => args.Result+=1;
   var result = processor.Process();
```

in an asynchronous world, where each concern may need to return a task, this isn't so simple. I've seen this done lots of ways, but I'm curious if there are any best practices that people have found. One simple possibility is

```
 public class Processor 
   {
        public IList<Func<ProcessingArgs, Task>> Processing { get; } =new List<Func<ProcessingArgs, Task>>();

        public async Task<int> ProcessAsync()
        {
            var args = new ProcessingArgs();
            foreach(var func in Processing) 
            {
                await func(args);
            }
            return args.Result
        }
   }
```

Is there some "standard" that people have adopted for this? There doesn't seem to be a consistent approach I've observed across popular APIs.

Comment: I am uncertain about what it is you are trying to do and why.

Comment: I am trying to delegate implementation concerns to an external observer (similar to polymorphism and a desire for composition over inheritance). Mainly to avoid a problematic inheritance chain (and actually impossible because it would require multiple inheritance).

Comment: Are the concerns related in any way and will they be processed in sequence or in parallel?

Comment: They seem to share access to the `ProcessingArgs` so I was confused about that.

Comment: Sequential - they are definitely related. One specific example is adding multiple steps/tasks required to complete a "transaction" (LOB functionality)

Comment: Ok that sounds like Chain of responsibility, (pipeline) similar to .net core middleware.

Comment: lol, I was adding that as an example in my previous comment

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't simply using an `event` (which is already a multicast delegate by default)?

Comment: That’s precisely the point of the question. Events can’t return a task. And even if I use a delegate that returns a Task of T, the result will get lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following delegate will be used to handle asynchronous implementation concerns

```
public delegate Task PipelineStep<TContext>(TContext context);
```

From the comments it was indicated

> One specific example is adding multiple steps/tasks required to complete a "transaction" (LOB functionality)

The following class allows for the building up of a delegate to handle such steps in a fluent manner similar to .net core middleware

```
public class PipelineBuilder<TContext> {
    private readonly Stack<Func<PipelineStep<TContext>, PipelineStep<TContext>>> steps =
        new Stack<Func<PipelineStep<TContext>, PipelineStep<TContext>>>();

    public PipelineBuilder<TContext> AddStep(Func<PipelineStep<TContext>, PipelineStep<TContext>> step) {
        steps.Push(step);
        return this;
    }

    public PipelineStep<TContext> Build() {
        var next = new PipelineStep<TContext>(context => Task.CompletedTask);
        while (steps.Any()) {
            var step = steps.Pop();
            next = step(next);
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```

The following extension allow for simpler in-line setup using wrappers

```
public static class PipelineBuilderAddStepExtensions {

    public static PipelineBuilder<TContext> AddStep<TContext>
        (this PipelineBuilder<TContext> builder,
        Func<TContext, PipelineStep<TContext>, Task> middleware) {
        return builder.AddStep(next => {
            return context => {
                return middleware(context, next);
            };
        });
    }

    public static PipelineBuilder<TContext> AddStep<TContext>
        (this PipelineBuilder<TContext> builder, Func<TContext, Task> step) {
        return builder.AddStep(async (context, next) => {
            await step(context);
            await next(context);
        });
    }

    public static PipelineBuilder<TContext> AddStep<TContext>
        (this PipelineBuilder<TContext> builder, Action<TContext> step) {
        return builder.AddStep((context, next) => {
            step(context);
            return next(context);
        });
    }
}
```

It can be extended further as needed for additional wrappers.

An example use-case of the delegate in action is demonstrated in the following test

```
[TestClass]
public class ProcessBuilderTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Should_Process_Steps_In_Sequence() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = 11;
        var builder = new ProcessBuilder()
            .AddStep(context => context.Result = 10)
            .AddStep(async (context, next) => {
                //do something before

                //pass context down stream
                await next(context);

                //do something after;
            })
            .AddStep(context => { context.Result += 1; return Task.CompletedTask; });

        var process = builder.Build();

        var args = new ProcessingArgs();

        //Act
        await process.Invoke(args);

        //Assert
        args.Result.Should().Be(expected);
    }

    public class ProcessBuilder : PipelineBuilder<ProcessingArgs> {

    }

    public class ProcessingArgs : EventArgs {
        public int Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t you want to await next then await step? I guess it depends if Add implies that you add code to execute before any other code that has been added. The way it is it’s more like an “insert”

Comment: @Jeff steps are by default executed in the order they were added to the pipeline. The default inline setup allows for you to change that manually if you wish in case there are post actions to be done on the way back up stream

Comment: How would you design/alter this if I wanted to use Task of T as a result instead of just setting context.Result? Would you just update the signatures and add an Insert method (instead of just Add) so that a middleware could communicate it’s result to another middleware?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it as delegates, you can:

```
public class Processor
{
    public event Func<ProcessingArgs, Task> Processing;

    public async Task<int?> ProcessAsync()
    {
        if (Processing?.GetInvocationList() is Delegate[] processors)
        {
            var args = new ProcessingArgs();
            foreach (Func<ProcessingArgs, Task> processor in processors)
            {
                await processor(args);
            }
            return args.Result;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```